# How do I setup VS to use ImageComparer in a non-UITest project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Simply adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting doesn't do the trick.

One error I receive complains about a missing DLL:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility
```

I would really like to compare 2 images using built-in MSFT libraries, but I can't seem to get around assembly issues for my console app, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The references are scattered depending on your particular version of Visual Studio. However, I was able to take a look at the dependency structure using Reflector, thus knew that the following dependencies needed to be added to get the class to function correctly:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.ExtensionUtilities
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback
```

And of course the main reference to:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
```

I found these assemblies split between the PrivateAssemblies & PublicAssemblies folder for Visual Studio 2015 in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
```

I then tested with a basic ImageCompare:

```
bool success = ImageComparer.Compare(img1, img2);
```

.. and started getting correct results. The MSFT docs on these particular libs are relatively scant, but seem to work well.